# C# Word Interop: SymbolMRU usage

Tags: c#, ms-word

I would like to show the recently used symbols in my MS Word addin but without the Symbols dialog window. I know that it is stored in the registry as SymbolMRU.
Is there a way to call this specific MRU somehow?